# what is the use of .data in pytorch

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network

I just got the code from https://github.com/heykeetae/Self-Attention-GAN (the file is spectral.py). Partial code is under there. I don't really understand what is the use of the .data, is this a method in some class? if it is, which class does it belong to?

```
import torch
from torch.optim.optimizer import Optimizer, required
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch import nn
from torch import Tensor
from torch.nn import Parameter

def l2normalize(v, eps=1e-12):
    return v / (v.norm() + eps)


class SpectralNorm(nn.Module):

    def _make_params(self):
        w = getattr(self.module, self.name)

        height = w.data.shape[0]
        width = w.view(height, -1).data.shape[1]

        u = Parameter(w.data.new(height).normal_(0, 1), requires_grad=False)
        v = Parameter(w.data.new(width).normal_(0, 1), requires_grad=False)
        u.data = l2normalize(u.data)
        v.data = l2normalize(v.data)
        w_bar = Parameter(w.data)
```

Comment: `.data` is an attribute of `w`, which is an instance of we don't know what (since `getattr(self.module, self.name)` could be literally anything). As a guess, `w.data` is a numpy array since it has a `.shape` attribute which is a `tuple`.

Comment: thanks dude, that helps a lot! I just checked the numpy document, and it says that the numpy.ndarray.data means "Python buffer object pointing to the start of the array’s data".

Comment: look at my answer. `data` is actually a `Tensor` object.

Answer (score -1):

OK so `SpectralNorm.__init__` sets `self.module = module` and `self.name = name` (default: `weight`) which is a constructor argument. This seems to be called like so `SpectralNorm(nn.Conv2d(3, conv_dim, 4, 2, 1)))` so `module` is an [`nn.Conv2d`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L179) instance which subclasses [`nn.Module`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L23) -- following the [trail](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html) we finally find the [answer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor)